# zoom on ion-slide not properly working - Ionic 6

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using Ionic 6 and wanted to zoom into a slide:

```
let zoom = this.slider.nativeElement.swiper.zoom;
    if(zoomIn){
      zoom.in();
      console.log("zoom in ")
     
    }else{
      zoom.out(); 
      console.log("zoom out ")
    }
```

This worked perfectly in Ionic 4, but using Ionic 6 it only works after zooming in/out in my Chrome Tab.
Can anybody help me with this?

I call the zoom function on this element:

```
  <ion-slides [options]="sliderOpts" #slider zoom>   
      <ion-slide>
        <div class = "swiper-zoom-container">
          <img src="{{ 1.jpg}}">
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

**UPDATE:**
changing the Viewchild Method and add the IonViewDidEnter() like following  solved the problem for me:

```
@ViewChild(IonSlides, {static: false})slider: IonSlides;


 ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.slider.update();
  }
```